# How to fix GDI+ Errors when downloading files?

Tags: c#

I have been making a client that installs a program I am also making. The problem is when I go to download the files. Sometimes, it gets stuck. I get thrown a error stating

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: 'A generic error occurred in GDI+.'

...and my UI freaks out (Buttons go blank, labels disapper, images go missing, ect). I have researched this error and it seems it happens with images, but I am downloading zip files that contain no images. I have found that it might have something to do with 5 files I am extracting from the zip files but thats not entirely accurate because it doesnt always happen and I have no real way to determine EXACTLY whats causing it. I suspect its because I cannot download so much in a short period of time but I do not know if this is why exactly either.

Also to add to this, the files still complete downloading when in debug mode, they ever continue through the async process, awaiting properly and everything.

I have tried narrowing down what file is causing it but I dont have any evidence to support it is a specific file. I have also tried spliting up the zip files to see if its the size of how much Im downloading at once, still no luck.

These are the download functions. 
The `RunWorkerTaskAsync()` is a custom reference I created to allow a worker to be "awaited". I privide the code below.(I take no credit as its pieces of code I have pulled from others)

```
        private async Task DownloadLibs()
        {
            Response.Text = "Updating Libraries...";
            this.Update();
            string url = @"http://akumamc.com/AkumaMC/Libraries.zip";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri(url);
                string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.AbsolutePath);
                await DLclient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(uri, @"C:\temp\" + fileName);
                DLclient.Dispose();
            }
            FileZipName = @"C:\temp\Libraries.zip";
            FileZipPath = @"C:\temp\.minecraft";
            Response.Text = "Extracting Libraries...";
            this.Update();
            await extractFile.RunWorkerTaskAsync();
        }
        private async Task DownloadMods()
        {
            Response.Text = "Updating Mods (1/2)...";
            this.Update();
            string url = @"http://akumamc.com/AkumaMC/Mods.zip";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri(url);
                string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.AbsolutePath);
                await DLclient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(uri, @"C:\temp\" + fileName);
                DLclient.Dispose();
            }
            FileZipName = @"C:\temp\Mods.zip";
            FileZipPath = @"C:\temp\.minecraft";
            Response.Text = "Extracting Mods (1/2)...";
            this.Update();
            await extractFile.RunWorkerTaskAsync();
        }
        private async Task DownloadExtras()
        {
            Response.Text = "Updating Mods (2/2)...";
            this.Update();
            string url = @"http://akumamc.com/AkumaMC/Mods2.zip";
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
            {
                Uri uri = new Uri(url);
                string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.AbsolutePath);
                await DLclient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(uri, @"C:\temp\" + fileName);
                DLclient.Dispose();
            }
            FileZipName = @"C:\temp\Mods2.zip";
            FileZipPath = @"C:\temp\.minecraft";
            Response.Text = "Extracting Mods (2/2)...";
            this.Update();
            await extractFile.RunWorkerTaskAsync();
        }
```

**RunWorkerTaskAsync:**

```
        public static Task<object> RunWorkerTaskAsync(this BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker)
        {
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

            RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler handler = null;
            handler = (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (args.Cancelled)
                    tcs.TrySetCanceled();
                else if (args.Error != null)
                    tcs.TrySetException(args.Error);
                else
                    tcs.TrySetResult(args.Result);
            };

            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += handler;
            try
            {
                backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
            catch
            {
                backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted -= handler;
                throw;
            }

            return tcs.Task;
        }
```

I expect the files to download without the form causing UI glitches and crashing.

**EDIT:** [Link](https://pastebin.com/D7svFn7m) to author's client code (taken from comment below)

Comment: GDI+ is complaining because you can only modify the UI from the program's main thread. i.e.: you should not be calling UI functions from within Tasks, which are being executed asynchronously in other threads.

Comment: What's `extractFile`? A `BackgroundWorker`? Also `RunWorkerTaskAsync` is called with `await` but is not `async`. What's `Response`? This code is a dog's breakfast, use either `Task` or `BackgroundWorker`, not both.

Comment: **1)** `DLclient` wouldn’t by chance be a COM object?   You shouldn’t be calling `Dispose()` **2)** how are you calling DownloadLibs and DownloadMods?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning incorrect. That is only true if say DownloadLibs is running in a Task that has not captured the UI context

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Alot of this code is a mess, first functionality then I will clean the code. I have a button click that awaits two functions. (CheckClient & CheckMods) Ignoring Check Client, CheckMods determines whether it is already installed if not it runs these three (normally 2) tasks. (DownloadLibs & DownloadMods) ```extractFile``` is a background worker (I am using a background worker to show progress on the extracting of zip files. Then i use downloadProgressChanged for the downloading of the files. Full code can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/D7svFn7m) at the pastebin

Comment: @MickyD ```DLclient``` should not be calling ```Dispose()```, I had that there due to the fact I was debugging using others solutions to similar issues. Sorry about that.

Comment: I suspect the problem is in your backgroundworker.DoWork.  Post that code

Comment: @MickyD Still unsure on what COM is but I believe ActiveX, its a default windows form using c# in visual studio if that helps at all. If COM is just a console based program (still unsure)

Comment: @MickyD Correction, I am using custom elements using Bunifu not COM i believe (Hopefully this isnt far off either)

Comment: What does Bunifu do?  The error you are getting implies COM due to “interop” error message.   COM can be finicky if called from wrong thread; calling it from multiple threads; deleting objects in incorrect way....  Please post **more code**

Comment: @MickyD https://pastebin.com/D7svFn7m < All code "Do work is under ```ExtractFile_DoWork```"

Comment: Hmm...it looks like there is the possibility you are calling `DoWork()` repeatedly before it has finished?  Thank-you for code link

Comment: @MickyD doesnt "await" wait for that task to finish before proceeding tho?

Comment: BackgroundWorker isn't a `Task`, so no

Comment: @MickyD Sorry i didnt specify, the ```RunWorkerTaskAsync()``` function was posted above by me in a dll (referenced) turning a backgroundworker into a task (kinda)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### This is a summary of my comments beneath the OP's question

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: 'A generic error occurred in GDI+.'

So the *"interop"* error implies some form of component object model (COM) problem and the things that stick out are:

1. the use of some 3rd party library that may be using COM
2. your `RunWorkerTaskAsync` extension method seems to be making multiple calls to `BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync` without first checking that the worker is busy.

`BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync()` is a `void`, it does not return a `Task` and so can't be used in `async/await`.  Therefore your extension method is essentially kicking off a background worker without waiting for it to complete.  Your extension method `RunWorkerTaskAsync()` (which isn't entirely `async`) returns immediately to those that called it.

You need to for the worker to complete before calling `RunWorkerAsync` again.

A possible fix:

1. Inside your extension method, check `BackgroundWorker.IsBusy` before telling it to run.  (A better way is to wait for `RunWorkerCompleted` and kicking off a new one there)
2. Call `RunWorkerAsync`
3. Because you want to wait for this "task" to complete before returning control to say `DownloadMods()`, your extension method will need to monitor `RunWorkerCompleted`.  This is kinda ugly as it goes against the original best practices of `BackgroundWorker` where everything is event-driven.

### Alternatives

Considering you are using `async/await` anyway, why use `BackgroundWorker` at all?  Consider wrapping up the essence of your extension method into a new method and call it via `Task.Run()`.

You can still have a `async Task ExtractFilesAsync` method that runs in a child task (because we used `Task.Run()` it will also be a child thread) can report progress.

Something like (pseudo code):

```
await Task.Run ( async () => await
    UnzipFilesAsync ( p => 
    {
       myProgressBar.BeginInvoke (new Action( () =>
                  myprogressBar.Progress = p; ));
    });

.
.
.
UnzipFilesAsync (Action<int> progressCallback) 
{
   .
   .
   .
   int percent = ...;
   progressCallback (percent);
}
```

*[Tell me more about async progress bar updates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36340639/585968)*

By the way, you shouldn't call `MessageBox.Show` or update the UI directly in a child thread, even if the call is a dialog with its own message pump.

Comment: Is there a way to check progress without using a background worker? on extracting zip files. I have researched this and a background worker seems like my only choice, this is why i am using both.

Comment: ```Task.Run()``` I beleive will not work due to the fact that it can not pull the background worker from that thread (Im kinda dumb) but it throws a error for that when I try to do so. Also, upon attempting to modify the ```RunWorkerTaskAsync()``` I have found checking if the background worker is busy doesnt seem to correct it. Calling RunWorkerAsync wont work sadly because i need to wait till it is complete before starting a new bgworker process. (If anymore clarification is needed please ask, sorry im a pain in the ass haha)

Comment: @Jamie yes you can.  People have been unzipping files from child threads way before `BackgroundWorker` came along.  _"i need to wait till it is complete"_ - I already told you that you need to do that but you **are not**.  You are doing multiple things wrong, and getting an error.  I'm a little puzzled why you don't want to change this code

Comment: I am sure you are right, I just do not know how to execute this. I need to learn more C# before doing a large project like this. I will deem this as a answer. Thank you for every bit of information you gave me and for being so kind!

Comment: Not a problem @Jamie.  Threading is a complex subject.  Though `async/await` is the preferred way, it does't mean its easier.  I think if you are just starting out particularly in WinForms, `BackgroundWorker` might be a good place to start.  Later you can move to `async/await`, generally you don't want to mix the older with the newer technologies though as they have different patterns  of usage as you have seen.  (one being event-driven for instance).  Good luck and thx for tick! :)