# Count elements asynchronously in an list in C#

Tags: c#, list, asynchronous

I'm filling a list with a function but I want to display how many elements are in list dynamically.
With my code, I have a NullReferenceException error.

My code is :

```
private async void FillListWithElements()
        {
            var list = await Task.Run(() => Functions.GetElements(param));
            DefineCurrentAction($"Element(s) in list : {list.Count}");
            Task.WaitAll();
            [...]
        }
```

`Functions.GetElements` is a static sync function in a library. (Pretty sure I should change something here)

`DefineCurrentAction` display text in a label to inform the user.

How can I display how much elements are in my list while the function GetElements is performing ?

Comment: What line throws the NullReferenceException?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?  Surely the number of elements in the list may be changing as you have not awaited the Task completion? Is the list you are using thread-safe?

Comment: @Fermin the line with await keyword

Comment: To answer your question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36340639/async-progress-bar-update

Comment: The exception is likely happening within the implementation of `Functions.GetElements(param)` and is being rethrown by the `await`. Run your code under the debugger to find where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: @Martin I want to show to user the list is incrementing

Comment: That's not quite what asynchronous is for. Asynchronous is for when you want to allow other processing while waiting for a slower media, typically db or network. You should probably think of implanting the update of the display as triggered by an event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way to couch this question would be to ask

"How can I get `GetElements` to **report** progress back to the caller?"

As such, say you changed the declaration of `GetElements` to

```
List<Something> GetElements(Some params, Action<int> progress)
{
     //...
     for(;;)
     {
         //do something
         progress?.Invoke(theCount)
     }
}
```

Now, when you call `GetElements`, you can supply a **function** (delegate) to receive the progress:

```
GetElements(params, count => Console.WriteLine(count))
```